# DOJO DataGrid+JsonRest+pagination

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

From what I have read on the internet about `DataGrid` pagination, I still can make it work. I have a `DataGrid` like this:

```
var grid = new DataGrid({ 
    store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: jsonrest_store}), 
    structure: [ 
        {name: 'aaa', field: 'aaa', 'width': initialCol1}, 
        {name: 'bbb', field: 'bbb', 'width': initialCol2}, 
        {name: 'ccc', field: 'ccc', 'width': initialCol3}, 
        {name: 'ddd', field: 'ddd', 'width': initialCol4} 
    ], 
    rowsPerPage: 10, 
    autoHeight: 8, 
    keepRows: 100 
}, "id_of_container"); 
grid.startup();
```

I tried different combinations of `rowsPerPage` and `autoheight(number/off)` but whenever I scroll down no call is made not even on the fetch of the `ObjectStore`. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Here's a good answer to your question i think : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620385/set-datagrid-to-show-just-5-rows-per-page

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have seen that and it is not helping exactly... The problem that I have is that no fetch is called on the scroll down of the table, and so no query on the jsonrest store is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this in your grid declaration

```
filter: {
             isServerSide: true,                 
 }
```

//It should fire the request automatically